# You’re now in the production slot, which is not recommended for setting up CI/CD

Tags: azure-functions, cicd

I want to set CI/CD for function app. I'm using Visual Studio Code Tools for deployment which overrides all content even for those functions as well which I didn't edit. So I need to manage source control for Function App.

Before enabling CI/CD, I want to know why Azure Portal is showing this message:

> You’re now in the production slot, which is not recommended for setting up CI/CD

And what will happen if I enable CI/CD. There are a lot of functions which are important to me. So I don't want to take risk before I move to next step.

Can anybody suggest me some article that can describe, why it is showing and what will be the effect if I enable CI/CD even after this message? what is best practice to enable CI/CD (with azure repos only) for function app in this case.

I didn't create any deployment slot or production slot.

Answer (score -1):

[image]
Deployed a function to Azure Portal Function App using VS Code.
If I go to Deployment Center > I can see the same message as you have shown
[image]

Even When you deploy the Function App from any Source Such as GitHub and disconnect it after deployment, you'll see the same message "`You’re now in the production slot, which is not recommended for setting up CI/CD`".

That means it is recommended to deploy/configure the function project to the different deployment slot like Staging, etc. other than the Prod Slot/Environment because if any changes of the function project is deployed to the production slot, it may become unavailable for some time until the deployment is completed and new code changes of that deployment may cause the breaking changes in the production slot site running which is not good.

Refer to the TechDirectArchive's [article](https://techdirectarchive.com/2022/09/29/how-to-deploy-code-from-github-to-azure-app-service-from-the-command-line/#:%7E:text=After%20the%20disconnection,%20you%20will,for%20setting%20up%20CI/CD.&text=This%20is%20because%20if%20a,until%20the%20deployment%20is%20finished.) for more information.